Are there any documented instances of ISIS violence against lesbians?
If not, are there any documented cases of persecution of lesbians with a lesser degree of severity like jail, penalties, social ostracization, etc? Do note I'm only talking about lesbians, not homosexuals in general.
Looking online, there are only cases of gay men being targeted.

While the act between two men is seen as a sexual intercourse by Islam (zina), the act between two women, surprisingly, is not (source). It is still not permissible but punishments, if any, are much less severe. I was not able to find any good sources for killings of lesbians by ISIS. For killing gays, these would not be difficult to find.

Interestingly this isn't a unique thing. IIRC the same thing occurred in medieval English law, where only male-male relationships were explicitly noted as illegal. It was only later made illegal when the laws got revised (I think around the Victorian period?).

Probably because both Christianity and Islam derive from the Hebrew Bible, which never mentions lesbianism, but does say that male-male homosexuality is a sin.

@kenod - Actually female-female relationships have never been illegal in the UK. There's a myth that Queen Victoria refused to give the Royal Assent to a law banning lesbian relationships because she refused to believe such a thing existed, but in fact such a law was never even proposed.

@KateBunting Huh, interesting, thanks! I remember reading before that one of the later laws which reduced prison sentences for male acts also criminalized lesbianism, but I guess I misremembered. Good to know!
